# SQL-CE possible bug?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

If I run this query, all of the [data].* values come out as NULL.
*ignore the `*`, it's just a test*

```
SELECT
  [map].*,
  [data].*
FROM
  f_normalised_report_hierarchy     AS [map]
LEFT JOIN
  f_normalised_report_data          AS [data]
    ON  (([data].level1_id = [map].level1_id) OR ([data].level1_id = 0))
    AND (([data].level2_id = [map].level2_id) OR ([data].level2_id = 0))
    AND (([data].level3_id = [map].level3_id) OR ([data].level3_id = 0))
    AND (([data].level4_id = [map].level4_id) OR ([data].level4_id = 0))
    AND (([data].level5_id = [map].level5_id) OR ([data].level5_id = 0))
    AND (([data].level6_id = [map].level6_id) OR ([data].level6_id = 0))
    AND ([data].metric_id = 22)
WHERE
  [map].level1_id = 22
```

Yet, it works fine if I add `1=1 AND` before each `[data].levelX_id = 0`!?!?

```
SELECT
  [map].*,
  [data].*
FROM
  f_normalised_report_hierarchy     AS [map]
LEFT JOIN
  f_normalised_report_data          AS [data]
    ON  (([data].level1_id = [map].level1_id) OR (1=1 AND [data].level1_id = 0))
    AND (([data].level2_id = [map].level2_id) OR (1=1 AND [data].level2_id = 0))
    AND (([data].level3_id = [map].level3_id) OR (1=1 AND [data].level3_id = 0))
    AND (([data].level4_id = [map].level4_id) OR (1=1 AND [data].level4_id = 0))
    AND (([data].level5_id = [map].level5_id) OR (1=1 AND [data].level5_id = 0))
    AND (([data].level6_id = [map].level6_id) OR (1=1 AND [data].level6_id = 0))
    AND ([data].metric_id = 22)
WHERE
  [map].level1_id = 22
```

I could almost live with that as a fudge to make it work, but it now takes forever to run.  (Up from under a second to 'still running' after 6 minutes.)

Am I being bind?  Or is SQL CE off it's rocker?

**EDIT**

If I reverse the conditions:

```
    AND (([data].level6_id = [map].level6_id) OR ([data].level6_id = 0))
```

to

```
    AND (([data].level6_id = 0) OR ([data].level6_id = [map].level6_id))
```

then I get different behaviour.

And if I use `IN` instead:

```
    AND ([data].level6_id IN ([map].level6_id,0))
```

I get different behaviour still.

None of the behaviours which sense, and certainly not what I have coded.

Comment: do any expressions in your conditions equal null?

Comment: Nope.  If they did `(1=1 AND NULL=0)` would still give `NULL`.

Comment: A reproducible script would be fantastic, although I know that might not be possible. Also, are your tables actually tables or are they table-valued functions?

Comment: I'll post a big chuck of examples in an answer to stop the question growing into a disertation.

Comment: SQL-CE can't have functions, views, etc, etc.

Comment: I'm going home now to cry.  And drink.  And iron.  Yey, what a Friday :)  Thanks guys for looking at this though.  Oh to return to enterpise installs of SQL Server 2005 and 2008.  All is forgiven, SQL-CE has destroyed my soul ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing these are likely slower, but I got both of these queries to work:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
  f_normalised_report_hierarchy     AS [map]
LEFT JOIN
  f_normalised_report_data          AS [data]
      ON  ([data].level1_id = [map].level1_id OR [data].level1_id*1 = 0)
      AND ([data].level2_id = [map].level2_id OR [data].level2_id*1 = 0)
      AND ([data].level3_id = [map].level3_id OR [data].level3_id*1 = 0)
      AND ([data].level4_id = [map].level4_id OR [data].level4_id*1 = 0)
      AND ([data].level5_id = [map].level5_id OR [data].level5_id*1 = 0)
      AND ([data].level6_id = [map].level6_id OR [data].level6_id*1 = 0)
;
```

And

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
  f_normalised_report_hierarchy     AS [map]
LEFT JOIN
  f_normalised_report_data          AS [data]
      ON  ([data].level1_id = [map].level1_id OR cast([data].level1_id as int) = 0)
      AND ([data].level2_id = [map].level2_id OR cast([data].level2_id as int) = 0)
      AND ([data].level3_id = [map].level3_id OR cast([data].level3_id as int) = 0)
      AND ([data].level4_id = [map].level4_id OR cast([data].level4_id as int) = 0)
      AND ([data].level5_id = [map].level5_id OR cast([data].level5_id as int) = 0)
      AND ([data].level6_id = [map].level6_id OR cast([data].level6_id as int) = 0)
;
```

**EDIT** With Compact 4 if it makes a difference.

Comment: May try them on Monday, but I'm not hopeful as it would likely change the execution plan to use table scans rather than index seeks/scans :(

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to abandon SQL-CE and do the join in memory in the client.

The only option that works is the last one, and performance on real data was appalling due to full scans of both tables.

```
CREATE TABLE f_normalised_report_data (
    level1_id       INT,
    level2_id       INT,
    level3_id       INT,
    level4_id       INT,
    level5_id       INT,
    level6_id       INT,
    metric_id       INT,
    value           MONEY,
    PRIMARY KEY (
        level1_id,
        level2_id,
        level3_id,
        level4_id,
        level5_id,
        level6_id,
        metric_id
    )
)
;

CREATE TABLE f_normalised_report_hierarchy (
    level1_id       INT,
    level2_id       INT,
    level3_id       INT,
    level4_id       INT,
    level5_id       INT,
    level6_id       INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (
        level1_id,
        level2_id,
        level3_id,
        level4_id,
        level5_id,
        level6_id
    )
)
;

INSERT INTO f_normalised_report_hierarchy SELECT 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6;
INSERT INTO f_normalised_report_hierarchy SELECT 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7;

INSERT INTO f_normalised_report_data      SELECT 1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 22, 999;
INSERT INTO f_normalised_report_data      SELECT 1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 7, 22, 911;

SELECT
    *
FROM
  f_normalised_report_hierarchy     AS [map]
LEFT JOIN
  f_normalised_report_data          AS [data]
      ON  ([data].level1_id = [map].level1_id OR [data].level1_id = 0)
      AND ([data].level2_id = [map].level2_id OR [data].level2_id = 0)
      AND ([data].level3_id = [map].level3_id OR [data].level3_id = 0)
      AND ([data].level4_id = [map].level4_id OR [data].level4_id = 0)
      AND ([data].level5_id = [map].level5_id OR [data].level5_id = 0)
      AND ([data].level6_id = [map].level6_id OR [data].level6_id = 0)
;
-- The above query gives me this...
-- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
-- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL

SELECT
    *
FROM
  f_normalised_report_hierarchy     AS [map]
LEFT JOIN
  f_normalised_report_data          AS [data]
      ON  ([data].level1_id = 0 OR [data].level1_id = [map].level1_id)
      AND ([data].level2_id = 0 OR [data].level2_id = [map].level2_id)
      AND ([data].level3_id = 0 OR [data].level3_id = [map].level3_id)
      AND ([data].level4_id = 0 OR [data].level4_id = [map].level4_id)
      AND ([data].level5_id = 0 OR [data].level5_id = [map].level5_id)
      AND ([data].level6_id = 0 OR [data].level6_id = [map].level6_id)
;
-- The above query gives me this...
-- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 22, 999
-- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 7, 22, 911
-- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 22, 999
-- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 7, 22, 911


SELECT
    *
FROM
  f_normalised_report_hierarchy     AS [map]
LEFT JOIN
  f_normalised_report_data          AS [data]
      ON  ([data].level1_id IN ([map].level1_id, 0))
      AND ([data].level2_id IN ([map].level2_id, 0))
      AND ([data].level3_id IN ([map].level3_id, 0))
      AND ([data].level4_id IN ([map].level4_id, 0))
      AND ([data].level5_id IN ([map].level5_id, 0))
      AND ([data].level6_id IN ([map].level6_id, 0))
;
-- The above query gives me this...
-- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 22, 999
-- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 7, 22, 911
-- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 22, 999
-- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 7, 22, 911


SELECT
    *
FROM
  f_normalised_report_hierarchy     AS [map]
LEFT JOIN
  f_normalised_report_data          AS [data]
      ON  ([data].level1_id = [map].level1_id OR (1=1 AND [data].level1_id = 0))
      AND ([data].level2_id = [map].level2_id OR (1=1 AND [data].level2_id = 0))
      AND ([data].level3_id = [map].level3_id OR (1=1 AND [data].level3_id = 0))
      AND ([data].level4_id = [map].level4_id OR (1=1 AND [data].level4_id = 0))
      AND ([data].level5_id = [map].level5_id OR (1=1 AND [data].level5_id = 0))
      AND ([data].level6_id = [map].level6_id OR (1=1 AND [data].level6_id = 0))
;
-- The above query gives me this...
-- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 22, 999
-- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 7, 22, 911
--
-- Which is correct, but performance was blown to smitherines.
```

Comment: Did you submit a bug report to Microsoft? https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback (note, you need to be logged in to submit feedback)